# Reidentify Person Using Color Histogram with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm attempting to reidentify people who leave and reenter the camera view for a video feed.

Using GluonCV I've ran [object detection](https://gluon-cv.mxnet.io/build/examples_detection/demo_ssd.html#sphx-glr-build-examples-detection-demo-ssd-py) on the initial frame from a video file (using OpenCV), extracted the users I want to track and assigned each an ID + stored the image of the person cropped to the bounding box. For each person I then perform object tracking using SiamRPN as described in the [GluonCV docs](https://gluon-cv.mxnet.io/build/examples_tracking/demo_SiamRPN.html#sphx-glr-build-examples-tracking-demo-siamrpn-py). When a person exits the frame the tracker loses them and I stop tracking.

The challenge is when they reenter a subsequent frame, I want to be able to re-identify the person. I rerun object detection every N frames to discover new people or people who have re-entered the frame. As a PoC I wanted to try and re-identify using their clothing because for my use-case, there are a finite number of people wearing different contrasting clothing.

My code so far:

```
from cv2 import cv2


def compare_hist(im1, im2):
    h, w, _ = im1.shape
    im2 = cv2.resize(im2, (w, h))
    test_image = cv2.cvtColor(im1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    query_image = cv2.cvtColor(im2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    # hist
    test_hist = calc_hist(test_image)
    cv2.normalize(test_hist, test_hist, 0, 1, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
    query_hist = calc_hist(query_image)
    cv2.normalize(query_hist, query_hist, 0, 1, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
    return cv2.compareHist(test_hist, query_hist, cv2.HISTCMP_CORREL)


def calc_hist(im):
    channels = [0, 1]
    bins = [50, 60]
    ranges = [0, 180, 0, 256]
    return cv2.calcHist([im], channels, None, bins, ranges)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    score = compare_hist(cv2.imread("a.png"), cv2.imread("b.png"))
    print(score)
```

However, this is giving inconsistent results and lots of false-positives unless I set the threshold very high which leads to false negatives. For example, image 1 below is a 73% match with image 2, but only 64% match with image 3:

1 [image: base image]
2 [image: test 1]
3 [image: test 2]

Comment: Why don't you just use the Hue values?

Comment: @IbrahimYousuf do you mean only compare the histogram for the hue channel? using only the hue channel suffers from the same issue where the best match is 1 and 2

Comment: Get a mean value of hue, or a dominant hue value and maybe compare them. Plus, hue values have ranges that we need to take care of.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by “hue values have ranges we need to take care of”?

Comment: I meant the hue value of color in image 1 will a bit different than the hue value in image 3. Colors have ranges. For instance, the red color is represented by hue value 0-30 as well as 150-180.